# Do advaita vedanta believes that itihaas(Ramayan and Mahabharata) are real history?

Tags: advaita, itihasa

Do advaita vedanta believes that Ramayan and Mahabharata are real history or they believe Mahabharata and Ramayan are mythology of legendary stories?

Comment: In Bhagavad gita bhAshya introduction, Adi Shankara refers to Vishnu's incarnation as Krishna. In Brahmasutra bhashya 3.1.19, Shankara refers to Sita as one who is not born in an ordinary way from a mother. Shankara also mentions about events in Mahabharata in his bhAshyas. It appears to me that Shankara considers both the itihasas to be (empirically) real. (Other advaitins like Madusudhana Saraswati also mention events in itihasas.)

Comment: @zero why from bhashya and why adi shankara. Can you quote. other scholar of advaita vedanta.

Comment: Can you explain what is the issue with quoting a bhAshya and also the issue with quoting Adi Shankara? I quoted because he is the most famous advaitin.

Comment: @zero no problem but, qouting bhashya will make it a bit difficult to understand. No problem with adi shankara but please qout it from his own original Sutra and not from his commantary.

Comment: I don't know about traditional Advaitins and their mathas I think they do consider them as real history. But modern Advaita organizations like Ramakrishna Mission and Chinmaya Mission consider Itihas as mythology. Only Vaishnavas organizations like ISKCON and maybe some other Vaishnava organizations like BAPS consider Itihas historical.